# PHP arrays for storing data

Tags: php, arrays

I am creating a site that requires a user to add tags to their forum. I have already implemented the form and button to add tags to an array, but I am wondering if there is a way in which:

when a user clicks on the "add tag" button again, it will add the new tag to the array even when the page refreshes...

Comment: It must go to the database! There are no other way to do this task, unless you do not need the tags forever. You can store the tags in a super global $_SESSION but it will die soon or later.

Comment: ok. just needed the tags to be stored somewhere before the "save" button was clicked and then sent to the database. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you'll probably want to use a database for what you're trying to do. An array in a php script is short-lived, it only exists for the duration of that single request.